# Validation error in Phoenix Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Using Elixir & Phoenix framework here.

I have a signup page where I'm validating the password & password confirmation fields using the `validate_confirmation` function.

```
def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
    |> validate_confirmation(:password)
    |> validate_length(:firstName, min: 2)
end
```

If I enter mismatching passwords, I get an error `no function clause matching in Gettext.dngettext/6` in the browser - https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDrxE.jpg

I have the latest dependencies before posting this.

The complete stacktrace is available here - http://pastebin.com/XLKav4cu

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the complete error message (including stacktrace) printed in the shell after this request is made?

Comment: @Dogbert here is the stacktrace - http://pastebin.com/XLKav4cu

Comment: Can you also post the source code of `web/views/error_helpers` and `web/templates/professional/form.html.eex`?

Comment: You were right... the upgrade docs (which I mistakenly ignored) mention updating the `error_helpers` - http://www.phoenixframework.org/blog/upgrading-from-11x-to-120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the old style syntax for Ecto.  You now need to cast, then pass to the `validate_required` function

```
def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
    model
    |> cast(params, [list of all fields])
    |> validate_required([list of required fields])
    |> validate_confirmation(:password)
    |> validate_length(:firstName, min: 2)
end
```

See https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.html#module-changesets for further details

Comment: Sorry but the error remains as is. Here's the model code - http://pastebin.com/CF7SneDY

Comment: Fixed the issue by following through on every step here - http://www.phoenixframework.org/blog/upgrading-from-11x-to-120 - I was resuming an old project, and didn't follow the upgrade news.